# How do I get started with Rust Macroquad on Windows?

Tags: rust, graphics

I recently started to learn Rust, and wanted to write a simple 2D game using Macroquad. Having tried various things I created the following minimal program:

```rust
use macroquad::prelude::*;

#[macroquad::main("BasicShapes")]
async fn main() {
    loop {
        next_frame().await
    }
}
```

This compiles fine, but when I try to run it a window briefly opens then I get:

> thread 'main' panicked at 'WGL: ARB_create_context_profile required!', C:\Users\beren.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\miniquad-0.3.16\src\native\windows\wgl.rs:395:13

Environment:

- Windows 10 (Windows 10 Pro 22H2)
- rust nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
- macroquad 0.3.26

Any ideas? What else do I need to set up or install for Macroquad to work?

Comment: What is your OpenGL Version?